# Load div according to ng-view name in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this `div - A`

```
<div class="container">
      <div ng-view="" autoscroll="true">
        <!--ANGULAR-INJECTED CONTENT-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

and `div - B`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div ng-view="transactions" autoscroll="true">
    </div>
```

I want to load `div - B` `if ng-view="transactions "` else load `div-A`

How do I do this?

Comment: This isn't something that Angular Router (`ng-view`) is capable of, to my knowledge.  This is definitely a feature of UI-Router (`ui-view`).  Look up "Named Views".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use ng-switch?
Try this:

```
<div ng-switch on="transactions">
      <div class="container-fluid" ng-switch-when="value1"><div autoscroll="true" /></div>
      <div class="container" ng-switch-default><div autoscroll="true"><!--ANGULAR-INJECTED CONTENT--></div></div>
</div>
```